# count characters while writing with raw_input

Tags: python

I am using `raw_input("> ")` to write something. And after that I am using `len()` to get the character count.

```
something = raw_input("> ")
print something
print len(something)
```

Is it possible to get the character count while writing at the beginning or the end of the text I write? So at the moment when I write `A test` (6 characters) I would like to see "6" in real time (e.g. at the beginning before the `"> "`
How can I do this?

Comment: In the python interpreter? I don't think so. But, in a GUI, you can.

Comment: Yes I would see this while writing in raw_input(), not in GUI.

Comment: Nope, I don't think that is achievable since you cannot control the python interpreter window. You would have to write your own GUI, with your own custom CLI (if that's what you need).

Answer (score 1):

Python is in line buffered mode by default, thus `raw_input` does not return until you press the enter key. If you want to read a single char immediately, see [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user).

Then you can do it this way though the need is rather useless I think:

```
getch = _Getch() #_Getch is defined in the post I mentioned above
a=''
cnt=0
inputs=''
while True:
    print '\r%6d> '%cnt, inputs, 
    a=getch()
    if ord(a) == 13:
        break
    cnt+=1
    inputs+=a

print '\nuser inputs:', inputs
```